# Where to store user-input parameters?

Tags: c#, wpf

Problem:
WPF application, no database.
It has main window, ribbon and there a button which opens new window, which has few checkboxes, textboxes which allows to set up parameteres how the job is gonna be done.

Now, how is the best way/best practice to store/save those parameteres and use them?
Settings class with properties and then creating global object when application starts? Then I could access this object in child window, save settings, then I could use such setting in MainWindow?

I guess it's a problem with OOP understanding.
Once I create Settings setting = new Settings(); in ChildWindow it is not accessible once window is closed.
But then, I've read somewhere to never set global objects and share them between windows.
Should I create Settings setting = new Settings() in MainWindow and then pass it in the constructor of ChildWindow? It could be like:
Settings setting = new Settings();
ChildWindow child = newChildWindow(setting);
Then in the new ChildWindow I could set up setting properties. As far as I know if you pass an object as a parameter it has reference to original object, so setting up properties in ChildWindow would affect MainWindow Settings object?

I know, the question is a bit messy, not sure if it's right place to ask such questions

Comment: I am not sure why can't you use app.config for your parameters. That way you dont have to worry about creating loading and saving it. You can even databind to your controls if you like. You can access the Properties.Settings statically.

Comment: Are you using the MVVM design pattern with your WPF application? If not, consider using MVVM, and then you might know precisely where (in which Model) to store these settings for access across the entire application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just have a small number of fields to store, then using the built in User scoped Settings would be the easiest way. They are stored in XML files and each user will have their own settings file in a hidden data folder. You can set them up in a dialog window in Visual Studio and then refer to them simply in your code like this:

```
this.BackColor = Properties.Settings.Default.myColor;
```

Saving them is just as easy:

```
Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
```

These examples are from the following linked page... to find out full details, take a look at the [Using Settings in C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730869%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) page on MSDN.